# Magento error - all admin pages give Fatal Error

Tags: admin, error, magento-ce

Following a connection failure during an update in Magento Connect I can no longer access any admin modules including login. I inadvertently exited to Admin rather than resolving the problem in Connect.

Front end of store is also offline but as store is used for eBay/Amazon only this is not a critical issue.

Error seen on every page is:
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options' not found in /*/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 200

This text is the only thing displayed on all pages.

Any suggestions on how I can restore my store? Or would it be better to start again from scratch - I have a backup of the SQL tables but no usable backup from within Magento. Lesson definitely learned on that one!

UPDATE:
I have updated the Core folder with the files from the Magento installation zip archive, and that has changed the error message to:

> "Fatal error: Interface 'Zend_Cache_Backend_Interface' not found in
>   /magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/ExtendedInterface.php on line 35"

Answer (score 2):

Most likely some files got missing during failed update. A reasonable way to recover is to download a vanilla Magento to your pc, extract the archive and copy app/code/core to your server with ftp/rsyn/sftp

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have updated the Core folder with the files from the Magento installation zip archive, and that has changed the error message to: "Fatal error: Interface 'Zend_Cache_Backend_Interface' not found in /magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/ExtendedInterface.php on line 35"

Comment: Upload lib folder also as the error says;)

Answer (score 0):

You web server doesn't have read privileges for those files. Also check out if file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php` exists. If this file is missing, something is wrong. Big times.